# Division of Nested XML Values with XSLT 1.0 on adjacent element match

Tags: xslt-1.0

I am attempting to divide two values from an xml where the ID and Date match but am not having luck referencing the second record's value. I have the below XML:

```xml
<Export>
    <Record>
        <ID>1000</ID>
        <Date>2022-08-15</Date>
        <Value>14.09059</Value>
    </Record>
    <Record>
        <ID>1000</ID>
        <Date>2022-08-15</Date>
        <Value>259.394</Value>
    </Record>
    <Record>
        <ID>2000</ID>
        <Date>2022-08-08</Date>
        <Value>32.01453</Value>
    </Record>
    <Record>
        <ID>2000</ID>
        <Date>2022-08-08</Date>
        <Value>467.052</Value>
    </Record>
</Export>
```

And am looking to achieve the below result:

```xml
<Export>
    <Record>
        <ID>1000</ID>
        <Date>2022-08-15</Date>
        <Value>18.409</Value>
    </Record>
    <Record>
        <ID>2000</ID>
        <Date>2022-08-08</Date>
        <Value>14.589</Value>
    </Record>
</Export>
```

Is this possible with XLST 1.0?

Answer (score 0):

If they are adjacent, you could do simply:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/Export">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each select="Record[position() mod 2 = 1]">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:copy-of select="ID | Date"/>
                <Value>
                    <xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::Record[1]/Value div Value" />
                </Value>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```