# Grouping 3 elements into a node

Tags: xslt, dynamic, tags, grouping

I have the following xml where a the xml element name have a number in it..

```
<Root>
      <Row>
        <Coverage>Partial</Coverage>
        <Admission>Self</Admission>
        <Sequence1>1</Sequence1>
        <Qualifier1>221</Qualifier1>
        <Date1>2017-06-01</Date1>
        <Sequence2>2</Sequence2>
        <Qualifier2>222</Qualifier2>
        <Date2>2022-05-06</Date2>       
      </Row>
      <Row>
       <Coverage>Partial</Coverage>
       <Admission>Self</Admission>
       <Sequence1>1</Sequence1>
       <Qualifier1>321</Qualifier1>
       <Date1>2017-06-01</Date1>
       <Sequence2>2</Sequence2>
       <Qualifier2>322</Qualifier2>
       <Date2>2022-05-06</Date2>        
      </Row>
      <Row>
        <Coverage>Full</Coverage>
        <Admission>Self</Admission>
        <Sequence1>1</Sequence1>
        <Qualifier1>421</Qualifier1>
        <Date1>2017-06-01</Date1>
        <Sequence2>2</Sequence2>
        <Qualifier2>422</Qualifier2>
        <Date2>2022-05-06</Date2>       
      </Row>
    </Root>
```

I would like to group Sequence, Qualifier and Date into a group node called Benefit like below. Also, Based on the first element "Coverage" value,  should be merged. XML output should as below.

```
<Root>
    <Row>
    <Coverage>Partial</Coverage>
    <Admission>Self</Admission>
    <Benefits>
        <Benefit>
            <Sequence>1</Sequence>
            <Qualifier>221</Qualifier>
            <Date>2017-06-01</Date>
        </Benefit>
        <Benefit>
            <Sequence>2</Sequence>
            <Qualifier>222<Qualifier>
            <Date>2022-05-06</Date>
        <Benefit>
        <Benefit>
            <Sequence>3</Sequence>
            <Qualifier>321</Qualifier>
            <Date>2017-06-01</Date>
        </Benefit>
        <Benefit>
            <Sequence>4</Sequence>
            <Qualifier>322<Qualifier>
            <Date>2022-05-06</Date>
        <Benefit>
      </Benefits>
    </Row>
    <Row>
    <Coverage>Full</Coverage>
    <Admission>Self</Admission>
    <Benefits>
        <Benefit>
            <Sequence>1</Sequence>
            <Qualifier>421</Qualifier>
            <Date>2017-06-01</Date>
        </Benefit>
        <Benefit>
            <Sequence>2</Sequence>
            <Qualifier>422<Qualifier>
            <Date>2022-05-06</Date>
        <Benefit>
    </Benefits>
   </Row>
</Root>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73383562/division-of-nested-xml-values-with-xslt-1-0-on-adjacent-element-match/73384064#73384064

Comment: Thanks Michael for the response. The solution in that link is for an entirely different scenario, I beleive, or I did not get it. My XML tag has a numeric value like Sequence1, Sequence2 etc that needs to be converted to 'Sequence' and numeric values should be the actual element value. Is it even possible?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. But if they are adjacent - i.e. they always come in a sequence of SequenceX, QualifierX, DateX - then the suggested method is much simpler.

Comment: P.S. Please state which version of XSLT your processor supports.

Comment: Version 2.0 is the one we use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a simple method, based on the assumption that the 3 elements to be grouped will always come in a contiguous block that starts with a `SequenceX`:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/Row">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="Coverage | Admission"/>
        <Benefits>
            <xsl:for-each select="*[starts-with(name(), 'Sequence')]">
                <Benefit>
                    <xsl:for-each select=". | following-sibling::*[position() &lt; 3]">
                        <xsl:element name="{translate(name(), '0123456789', '')}">
                            <xsl:value-of select="." />
                        </xsl:element>
                    </xsl:for-each>                     
                </Benefit>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </Benefits>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

If the above assumption is not true, you can perform actual grouping based on the number included  in the element names:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/Row">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="Coverage | Admission"/>
        <Benefits>
            <xsl:for-each-group select="*[matches(name(), '^Sequence|^Qualifier|^Date')]" group-by="replace(name(), '\D', '')">
                <Benefit>
                    <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
                        <xsl:element name="{replace(name(), '\d', '')}">
                            <xsl:value-of select="." />
                        </xsl:element>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </Benefit>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
        </Benefits>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: The works perfectly Michael. Thank You. Is there a way to get rid of the numeric value from the tag name when copy is done. Like 'Sequence' instead of 'SequenceX' ?

Comment: Sorry, I missed that requirement. Fixed now.

Comment: Thank You Michael. Perfect solution. I understood how it is done.

Comment: Hi Michael, taking this one step further, I updated the Original question with a new/change requirement. Could you please help solve the final piece of the puzzle? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The input you show now is not a well-formed XML document. You must have a single root element.  -- P.S. I believe the change required to the XSLT is trivial and you should be able to handle it yourself.

Comment: Fixed the XML to make it well-formed. I tried few hours and still could not get it working. :-(

Comment: Seriously? All it requires is a very basic knowledge of XSLT.

Comment: Yeah, not well versed with xslt. Still trying to learn. :-)